# How to delete duplicate value in a single row which stats from D4 in excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning macro through the websites,

I am don't know how to put macro for this scenario, which is my value stats from the cells `D8` and its end in `AE8`, which contains lot of duplicate values I want to delete the repeated values in this row by not having blanks, this procedure again want to starts from four columns downs (c = c + 4). I hope this question makes sense, can anyone help me?

**UPD:**

```
With Range("D8:AE8")
    .Value = .Value
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    On Error Resume Next
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftRight
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: show us please what have you tried so far?

Comment: With Range("D8:AE8")
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftRight
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

Comment: I want to delete the repeted values with in that range,and also want to delete the blanks.

Comment: does it matter which occurance of duplicate value to delete, first or last?

Comment: I'm trying to delete the duplicate values between a set of columns in a row...Where im getting the same value repeated in following or somewhere in the range...just need to delete the duplicate one and replace with the unique value...Ex: 1 2 2 4 5 3 2 this is the scenario...i want the output as 1 2 4 5 3

Comment: AE8 is the last cell which starts from D8

Comment: Updated your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For j = 8 To 20 Step 4
    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & j & ":AE" & j)
        .Value = .Value
        For i = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, .Cells(1, i)) > 1 Then .Cells(1, i).ClearContents
        Next i
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftToLeft
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Next j
```

Comment: no its not deleted values in the cells.will you pls suggest me some other codings

Comment: @user3482108, check please whether your range `D8:AE8` really contains duplicates and also try updated answer

Comment: @user3482108, `Ex: 1 2 2 4 5 3 2 this is the scenario...i want the output as 1 2 4 5 3` - the code does exactly what you want

Comment: @user3482108, see my updated answer for `("D12:AE12"),("D16:AE16"),("D20:AE20")`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Simco & Siddharth,its very usefull

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to th relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("D8:AE8")

        '~~> Looping from Column AE to D in reverse order
        For i = 31 To 4 Step -1
            '~~> Check if it is a duplicate
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, .Cells(8, i).Value) > 1 _
            Then .Cells(8, i).ClearContents
        Next i
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: but this coding is not deleted any cells. i need like this eg:      1 6 3 3 5 4 5 6,i want the output as 1 6 3 5 4

Comment: The code does exactly what you asked for in the question.

Comment: @user3482108, believe, Siddharth Rout is the most trusted person I ever know on this site:) All his solutions are tried and tested. I've just also tried this code and it works well.

Comment: sorry mistake is mine its really works,thanks for your help.can you explain the line i=31 to 4 step -1.

Comment: it is reverse looping. 31 is column number of AE, 4 is column number of D, so we loop through each column from AE to D (reverse loop)

Comment: This coding used in that particullar range only("D8:AE8").but this scenario want to repeat in 4 coloums down,like ("D12:AE12"),("D16:AE16"),("D20:AE20").....etc.can you help me

Comment: @user3482108: Use two loops. One for the row which will be something like `For J = 8 to 20 Step 4` and then inside that loop put the above loop. You will have to change the above code accordingly. I can give you the code but I would like you to try it first :)

Comment: @simoco: Guess my above comment comes in too late. I just saw OP's comment below your post :D